# How to hide some rows of an One2many field in Odoo 10?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

May be I am a bit distracted with the current situation, but I cannot understand why this is not working:

I have a model, named `my.comodel`. This model has a field named `invisible`, a *Boolean*.

On the other hand, I have another model, which has an *One2many* field named `my_o2m_field` and points to `my.comodel`. I just want that this field shows only the records whose field `invisible` is *False*:

```
my_o2m_field = fields.One2many(
    comodel_name='my.comodel',
    inverse_name='my_m2o_field',    
    domain="[('invisible', '=', False)]",
    # domain=[('invisible', '=', False)],
    string='Test',
)
```

I have tried with both domains (and a lot more) with no result. The point is when I go to the technical interface and look for the field in the database structure, the field is updated with all the changes I did to it, except for the domain, which always remains empty. And if I try to modify it through the interface just to test, I get the message which warns you to change field properties by code, not by interface.

Any ideas of what is happening? Or how can I manage what I want? I have an idea but it would be too messy.

Comment: did you added the field "invisible" on the form view?

Comment: Yes, in fact I put it visible and it works ok. The problem is that the lines with the field `invisible=True` do not disappear.

Comment: I have added the answer in my post. So feel free to upvote so in future others ca trusted this as an answer and get to know further for the same issue.

Comment: Hi @Dipen, I think you misunderstood me. I already had the field in the view, and it takes ok its value. But the domain does not work. I can see lines with the boolean field `invisible=True` when my purpose is not to see them through the domain.

Comment: Ops.! sory for added as the answer.So on the domain can you try to reverse the condition -> invisible != True.

Comment: Yes, I have tried before, even to use other field in the condition, but the domain never works.

Comment: is there any way to set the invisible field value = true/false or it's by default false?

Comment: By default is False, but there is a way, with an `onchange` method. The `onchange` changes the value `invisible`, and works ok. The problem is that the domain does not hide the records. May be because there are not saved yet? I do not remember that condition. Anyway, I cannot save them as the model is a Transient Model.

Comment: yes is it is the Transient Model then it can not permanently store your value. If the default is false then on your one2many you will have all the false record right? once you perform the onchange and value is a store and then you will behave the result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210219/discussion-between-dipen-shah-and-forvas).